# excel conditional to R

Tags: r, excel

I want to create two variables vector:
first one is a crescent number went meet some conditions.
In Excel, I have this formula

```
year1=IF(O(AM57=1;AO57=1;AQ57=1;AS57=1);0;1)
year2=IF(AT57=1;1;IF(B57=$C$50;1;B57+1))
year3=IF(AT58=1;1;IF(B58=$C$50;1;B58+1))
year4=IF(AT59=1;1;IF(B59=$C$50;1;B59+1))
```

.
.
.

But I have n=1445 and years for n are 9465 rows

Another variable has

```
ageid1=NORMINV(RANDOM();C$55;C$54)
ageid1=IF(OR($AT57=1;$B57=$C$50);NORMINV(RANDOM();C$55;C$54);C57+1)
ageid1=IF(O($AT58=1;$B58=$C$50);NORMINV(RANDOM();C$55;C$54);C58+1)
ageid1=IF(O($AT59=1;$B59=$C$50);NORMINV(RANDOM();C$55;C$54);C59+1)
ageid2==IF(O($AT65=1;$B65=$C$50);NORMINV(RANDOM();C$55;C$54);C65+1)
```

.
.
.

Please some help me to translate this kind of conditions.

Thank you.

PD. Thanks @jared-mamrot

Comment: You can use `ifelse()`, e.g. `ifelse(AT57 == 1, 1, ifelse(B57 == C50, 1, B57 + 1))` but instead of referencing cells, you reference values, e.g. if you have a dataframe called "df" you could refer to specific 'cells' by their index: `ifelse(df[2,3] == 1, 1, ifelse(df[4,5] == df[2,2], 1, df[7,8] + 1))`. See https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/model-a-quantitative-trading-strategy-in-r/chapter-1-introduction-to-r-for-trading?ex=4 for more details. Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Using `ifelse` on a single cell of a frame is the wrong approach. The question is unclear at the moment if you're concerned with just a single cell or if you intend to do this on columns or rows of a table. Marcelo, please [edit] your question and provide usable sample data by pasting the output of `dput(x)` where `x` is a small, representative sample of whatever R data you are using.

Comment: @r2evans thank you, but I don't have a data set, because I try to make a df whit conditionals values and follow the same structure as excel (the Excel is a mess)

Comment: I don't understand. If you have data in Excel and want to do something with it in R, then that is your dataset. Start with the raw data (no excel formulas) and define what you need to do to mimic what is being done in Excel.

Comment: Of course, I have already passed many columns to R to define how you indicate, but to create those last variables I do not know how to call the condition so that a number grows when it reaches some conditions.
For example, the age of one of the people who begins in the sample is 20, throughout 29 years in the study "$C$50" and fulfilling some conditions such as dummys (0,1) must increase the age until they is die. "$AT== 1"

Comment: Thank you @jared_mamrot 
The line runs perfect but it doesn't increase the value, it just adds up to 1 and 2, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Conditions 0,1 are already created correctly.
I have already passed many columns to R to define the rows and columns. For example, the age of one of the people who begins in the sample is 20, throughout 29 years in the study "$C$50" and fulfilling some conditions such as dummys (0,1) the age must increase until death . "$AT== 1"

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).